# Disabling PowerApps button on SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, pnp-powershell, flow, powerapp

I am attempting to disable the PowerApps button on the hero ribbon without success.

I've tried the following:

```
Set-SPOSite –Identity SiteUrl -DisableAppViews Disabled -DisableFlows Disabled
```

and

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url <site url>

$ctx = Get-PnPContext

$ctx.Site.DisableAppViews = $true;

$ctx.Site.DisableFlows = $true;

$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Using Sharepoint Online management shell - you should pass $true instead of ”disabled” for both the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It is not yet supported to hide the Power Apps button from list menu.

The parameter `DisableAppViews` hides only **See all apps** option. The **Custom forms** button is not possible to hide (while keeping the Power Apps function) using OOB solution for the time being.

---

However, you can hide **Power Apps** option from list/library command bar at the top using JSON formatting.

Use JSON like below in view formatting option:

```
{
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "powerApps",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Microsoft Documentations**:

1. [Command bar customization syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting)
2. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

**Output**:

1. **Before Applying JSON formatting**

   [image]
2. **After Applying JSON formatting**

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Ganesh, JSON formatting could hide the button.
Providing test result for your reference:

Before applying the JSON code:
[image]

After applying JSON code:
[image]
*As we cannot provide images in comments, so I post the reply as answer.*